# How to invoke Spring setter method before any other class constructor get invoke?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have an action class and that class will have a BOC object that will fill with Spring Dependency Injection. Below shows the sample code:

```
public class ActionCls {
  private BOC theBoc = null;

  /*** theBoc getter / setter ***/
}
```

If I want to call a member function, say `thefunc`, that belong to `BOC` inside the `ActionCls` constructor, like this:

```
public class ActionCls {
   private BOC theBoc = null;

   ActionCls() {
      theBoc.thefunc();
   }
}
```

a runtime error will be thrown saying that `theBoc` is null. I did try to use `init-method` in spring configuration like this:

`<bean id="theBoc" class="com.huahsin68.BOC" init-method="thefunc"></bean>`

Anyhow this doesn't help because even though `thefunc` is get called first, but the `theBoc` setter is invoke only after `ActionCls` constructor. Is that a way to call `theBoc` setter 1st then only `ActionCls` constructor? So that `theBoc` is not null and I can invoke `thefunc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't expect to call a getter or setter on a class BEFORE its constructor is called. What you want to achieve is not possible. You can better create a parametrized constructor, in which you init theBoc with some argument, using the `constuctor-arg` param on your ActionCls bean, then call the method:

```
public class ActionCls {
   private BOC theBoc = null;

   ActionCls(BOC theBoc) {
      this.theBoc = theBoc
      theBoc.thefunc();
   }
}
```

Then you can define your constructor arg like that:

```
<bean id="actionCls" class="foo.bar.ActionCls">
        <constructor-arg ref="boc"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

While you can't do what you're asking for (calling a method on property in the constructor, while the property is set via a mutator), you can make use of `@PostConstruct` to get Spring to invoke a method on your bean once it's been properly assembled.

```
class ActionCls {
  @Inject
  private BOC boc;

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {
    boc.func();
  }
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to baba's answer, you can use `init-method` (or `@PostConstruct`) to solve this problem, but it should be used on `ActionCls` rather than on `BOC`:

```
public class ActionCls {
    ...
    public void init() {
       theBoc.thefunc();
    }
}
```

.

```
<bean ... class="com.huahsin68.ActionCls" init-method="init">...</bean>
```

I think this approach is more elegant, because init method is guaranteed to be executed when the bean is fully initialized, so that it doesn't depend on type of injection (setter or constructor) you use for your dependencies.

Comment: True, this is the best approach, and the approach what I would use, but the OP specifically asks how to call a member function in the constructor.